# OpenStreetMap leafletjs remove tree layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

How do I remove the tree layer(maybe it is a tileLayer) on openstreetmap as you can see in the picture below. Is there a way to remove all the dots and lines on the map as well?

[image]

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    scrollWheelZoom: false
}).fitBounds(
    [
        [driverLocation.latitude, driverLocation.longitude],
        [customerDeliveryLocation.latitude, customerDeliveryLocation.longitude]
    ],
    { padding: [80, 80] }
);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> bidragsgivare'
}).addTo(map);

var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: { iconSize: [34, 34] }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained by @ghybs, Leaflet loads images that are already rendered, so you cannot change them on the fly.

If you you want to try different map providers, have a look at this project : https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ and pick the style that best suits your needs.

You can also try [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/) if you want to design your own style.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a Leaflet [Tile Layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer), it loads *raster* tiles, i.e. plain images. For example:

[image: Tile from OSM]
<sub>© [OpenStreetMap](https://osm.org/copyright)</sub>

Therefore you will understand that it is complicated to modify those images on the fly in the browser.

But you can try to find other Tile Sources that serve different styles. E.g. you can browse on [Leaflet-providers demo](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/index.html).

Some example of other Tile Sources:

[image: Tile from OSM.de]
<sub>© [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)</sub>

[image: Tile from OSM.fr]
<sub>© Openstreetmap France | © [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)</sub>

[image: Tile from OSM.se]
<sub>Tiles courtesy of OpenStreetMap Sweden — Map data © [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)</sub>

If you want to further customize the tiles, you should serve them with your own Tile Server, or use online services that enable you to specify your own style (e.g. Mapbox).

You could also use vector tiles, so that the style is applied directly by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define Id for the map like so:

```
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
bidragsgivare'
}).addTo(map);
```

All valid Map IDs(for mapbox) can be found here : https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#maps

More information can be found at link : 
http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/